# Comparing SHA1 hash to login in wordpress account

Tags: wordpress, sha1

im totally lost on this one.
I have a client that asked me to create a xml api to use with an iphone app on his website. The iphone app developer is sending the auth values with a SHA1 encrypted password.

How can i check that the username(plain text) and password(Sha1) is correct ??

I´ve reading class.phpass.php , and plugable.php but i cant figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to take a bit of work. The WP password is stored as a salted MD5 hash, which can't possibly match the SHA1 you are being sent. Furthermore, because the "cleartext" of the password is not saved, you don't have it available to automatically generate an additional SHA1 value.

Here's a couple of suggestions off the top of my head on how to attack this problem:

1. Have the app connect using HTTPS and then send the cleartext of the password. This the most secure and it requires the least reworking of the WP code, but it may not be an option available to you.
2. Have the app send the password encrypted with a symmetrical cypher, with both the app and WP knowing the secret key. The management of a secret key in multiple locations is dicey. You pretty much have to assume that it's eventually going to leak and then any security goes out the window.
3. When a user successfully logs in to WP (or when they are created, or when they change their password), create a user meta value which is a SHA1 of the password. Then it is available for future authentication with the app.

Depending on the specifics of the site, items #2 and #3 are not really secure. #2 is just waiting for a hack, and unless #3 happens over an encrypted connection, it is effectively sending a cleartext password (in the form of the SHA1) over the net.

If you can't get the app developer to do #1, then I suggest you go with  #3 and hope no one is really interested in whatever info the site is managing.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions Peter, i will talk with the iphone dev and let you know